# ScrollTop Jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I have been using the ScrollTop JQuery so that when buttons are clicked in the right hand column, they scroll to the specific id in the left. It goes to the specific id when I first load the page, but after that it doesn't go to the other three, but glitches out going up or down slightly when buttons are clicked. I found that when I scroll to the top of the page and click the link it goes to the correct place, so it seems it it trying to find the top position of the left column and trying to go from there. No ideas as to how to fix this so would appreciate any thoughts.

CSS:

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
}


#main,
#col_l,
#col_r
{
height: 100%;
}

div[id*="col"]{
float: left;
width: 50%;
overflow: auto;
}   

#col_r{
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
```

JS:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      

$("#stsp").click(function() {
$('#col_l').animate({
scrollTop: $("#lgg").offset().top}, 2000);
});

$("#fg").click(function() {
$('#col_l').animate({
scrollTop: $("#funny").offset().top}, 2000);
}); 

$("#covers").click(function() {
$('#col_l').animate({
scrollTop: $("#coverso").offset().top}, 2000);
});

$("#demo").click(function() {
$('#col_l').animate({
scrollTop: $("#mp3").offset().top}, 2000);
});

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="col_r">

<div id="hb"><a href="Foreigner.zip"><button id="demo">One &times; Fifteen (64mb)   </button></a></div>
<div id="lg"><button id="stsp">Same Time Same Place</button></div>
<div id="fg"><button id="funny">Funny Games Funny Games</button></div>
<div id="c"><button id="covers">Covers Over Covers</button></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Reviving an old question, yaay. Remember to clear the floats of whatever divs you're trying to get the offset of. Otherwise you're going to get false values which might be what was causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed this using the ScrollTo Jquery:http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

I'm not sure why I was having problems with the ScrollTop Jquery.